# How can I do data-target="#userId" in thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

How can I user data-target="#userId" in a thymeleaf HTML doc.
For like ,In any JSP or any HTML ,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resetPwModal${customer.uuid }">reset</a>
```

How I write in a thymeleaf HTML doc.
like this?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-th-target="#resetPwModal${customer.uuid }">reset</a>
```

the exception is :

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "#" (user/userList.html:90)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
th:attr="data-target='#customerModel'+${customer.uuid }"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
th:data-target="${'#customerModel'+customer.uuid}"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.