# Thymeleaf Concatenation

Tags: html, spring-boot, concatenation, thymeleaf

I don't know how  to concatenate

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_form_inline"> Bloqué</button>
```

and

```
th:text="${z.idp}"
```

---

I wanna to concatenate `th:text="${z.idp}"`    with    `data-target="#modal_form_inline"`

the result would like next:

- `modal_form_inline1` or `modal_form_inline2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do data-target="#userId" in thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397240/how-can-i-do-data-target-userid-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: @Pau thank you sir